# React native inline arrow function, with parameter. Confusing definition

Tags: reactjs, react-native, arrow-functions

I have a series of react native TouchableHighlights, each with a key prop (they are generated from an iterator). I want to give each an onPress function that is aware of its key parameter.

I have read that class based arrow functions are generally best practice, so I tried this:

```
handlePress = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.key)
}

<TouchableOpacity key={key} onPress={this.handlePress} />
```

No dice, event is null.

So then I tried:

```
handlePress = (key) => {
    console.log(key)
}

<TouchableOpacity key={key} onPress={() => this.handlePress(key)} />
```

**This works**

However, this also works:

```
handlePress(key) {
    console.log(key)
}

<TouchableOpacity key={key} onPress={() => this.handlePress(key)} />
```

I thought that either one, or the other would fail. Are these functionally identical, or is there some subtlety that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

There are basically two differences between normal functions and arrow functions in javascript.

1. binding
2. syntax

## Binding

---

If you try to use `this` inside normal function, it will throw some error. 
e.g.:

```
class example {

    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    someFunc() {
        console.log(this.props);
    }

    someFunc();

}
```

This will fail.

To fix it, you should bind it manually in the constructor of the class like this:

```
class example {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.someFunc = this.someFunc.bind(this);
    }

    someFunc() {
        console.log(this.props);
    }

    someFunc();

}
```

On the other hand, you don't need to bind arrow functions. It will get context by default. So, this code is perfectly valid:

```
class example {

    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    const someFunc = () => {
        console.log(this.props);
    }

    someFunc();

}
```

## Related to your question:

---

If you also want `event` in any function (normal or arrow), you can do this:

Using arrow function:

```
handlePress = (event, key) => {
    console.log(event, key)
}

<TouchableOpacity key={key} onPress={event => this.handlePress(event, key)} />
```

Using normal function:

```
handlePress(event, key) {
    console.log(event, key)
}

<TouchableOpacity key={key} onPress={event => this.handlePress(event, key)} />
```

Comment: Hi, this is helpful, thank you, but I'm looking for the difference (if any) between the last two options in my question, and which is best practice.

Comment: Actually, I've looked through some old code I had, and onPress={this.handlePress}, and handlePress = event => { something with event.target } does seem to work on React.

Comment: @Alex you have 3 code blocks in your question. If you don't want any parameters, Use first code block whenever possible. If you want to pass parameter, to function, use second code block, use third code block only when context is important.

Comment: @Alex In short, first option is highly performant and best to use. second and third are equal in performance, but using arrow function approach whenever you can, will be a good idea, as you don't have to manually bind it and will match the code of most of the developers.